# "One off" error in numpy.r_ array construction

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I want to construct an array in Python/numpy using the r_ operator like so.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.r_[0.02:0.04:0.01]
array([ 0.02,  0.03])
>>> np.r_[0.04:0.06:0.01]
array([ 0.04,  0.05])
```

Both cases work as expected. If I change the limits though:

```
>>> np.r_[0.03:0.05:0.01] #?????
array([ 0.03,  0.04,  0.05])
```

Why does this happen? Is it something to do with an inexact floating point representations? Or is this a bug?

Comment: The linked answer does not mention `np.r_` at all.  That answer is relevant because `np.r_` can use `arange`, but it isn't an exact duplicate.  Lucky I  got my answer in just under the wire.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a complex 'step' this uses `linspace`:

```
In [68]: np.r_[0.02:.04:3j]
Out[68]: array([ 0.02,  0.03,  0.04])

In [69]: np.r_[0.03:.05:3j]
Out[69]: array([ 0.03,  0.04,  0.05])
```

With the float 'step' it uses `arange`, which has a note that results can be inconsistent with non integer steps.  It recommends `linspace` for more control.

`np.mgrid` also accepts the psuedo-complex step notation.

Look in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/index_tricks.py` for more details on how these classes work.